# Python password_hash PHP

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

В базе данных хранятся пароли созданные интруметом PHP password_hash (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php). Возможно ли средствами python проверить, соответствует ли пароль хешу?

Comment: Да, если есть реализация нужного алгоритма хеширования для Python и известна соль.

Comment: соль там внутри

Comment: Странно, что нет Python-библиотеки, которая повторяла бы поведение password_hash. Сделать самому и опубликовать на PyPI, что ли... 

Comment: на самом деле есть

Comment: @Ипатьев значит её автор не умеет в SEO, потому что она совершенно не гуглится

Comment: не знаю мне выдало первой ссылкой

Comment: @Ипатьев в первой ссылке мне ничего не выдало, а во второй библиотека с последним коммитом в январе 2012-го, это никуда не годится

Comment: @Ипатьев, я тоже искал и как то ничего не нашел, нельзя ли посмотреть на то что вы нашли?

Comment: вторая ссылка по запросу заголовка этого вопроса в гугл https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871295/migrate-bcrypt-password-hash-from-php-to-python-valueerror-invalid-hashed-pas

Comment: @Ипатьев это всего лишь bcrypt, а не password_hash. Странно, что мне приходится пересказывать PHP-документацию человеку, который вроде как считается спецом по PHP, но если вы не знали, функция password_hash поддерживает не только bcrypt (см. второй аргумент `$algo`)

Comment: Впрочем, тем не менее, если автору вопроса не нужно ничего кроме bcrypt, то библиотеку `py-bcrypt` действительно можно использовать для реализации части функционала password_hash